# How to remove border around hyperlink image in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I can not remove these border from my hyperlink image:
[image: 1]
I tried:

```
a img {border: none}

img {border: none}

a {border: none}

* {
    outline: none;
    border: none
}
```

I tried `border: 0;` too.
But it's not working. Tested on Windows 7 Ultimate using Firefox 35.
[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/mocoyu/1)
Hard reload if you can't see it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, are you sure it is not caused client-side? Anyway, you can always try `border: 0px !important;` to test if that removes it.

Comment: If images aren't loaded (as in your screencap) it is common for browsers to throw a border around said image (depending on your browser).

Comment: @Kevin Voorn I don't know, there is a website, wookmark.com, everything is normal in that website, no borders around image

Comment: @KevinVoorn `0x` is not a valid border size.

Comment: @DaveLunny I meant `0px`, my bad. I've edited the comment.

Comment: @KevinVoorn just wanted to clarify for @crezc3nt... you know the `px` part of that can safely be omitted as well. Tools like [csscomb](https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js) will strip out any `0` value's units.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is not best practice and could be throwing off the browser. Make sure you end each line with a semicolon `;`

```
a img { border: none; }

img { border: none; }

a { border: none; }

* {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: No, we don't have to put a semicolon after the _last_ declaration.

Comment: @user3790069 True, but browsers can be picky and besides, it is not good practice.

Answer (score 1):

The displayed placeholder in `img` tags for broken links is controlled by the browsers, and the border may be included in the placeholder image (or not, but that's not the point).

In this case, you just can't do anything about this border (but avoid broken links).